# What's the best practice to locate a component on a page in web app during a test?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, testing, web-applications, jestjs

I see many examples of locating an element via a class or even HTML tag, which personally I don't find too reliable.

I've noticed an approach to leverage `data-` attribute for components, e.g. `data-test`.

Is it a good practice to add `data-test` attribute to a component to check for its presence and interaction with it? Is there a better approach than that?

I would use it like so:

```html
<span data-test="add-descriptors-btn" class="medium-text">Add Descriptors</span>
```

I've tried to look around for other approaches, but all I find is very basic examples, which don't look like something that could used in a production service.

Just to make it clear, I'm asking not "how to", but how it is done appropriately in big projects.

Comment: Might want to check out [@testing-library/vue](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro). I haven't used it for Vue, but I've used it for React. It takes a different approach than some other testing frameworks, which may be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: `data-testid` is pretty much a standard. As long as there's a convention, extra attrs can be removed wuth a transform from production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common ways of doing this in Vue is by [using the `ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

Ref functions similar to an ID but instead of being globally unique, it is unique to a given instance of a component.

You can have multiple copies of the same component with the same ref, or even multiple of the same ref across different components.

For example:

```
<input type="text" ref="input">
...
console.log(this.$refs.input.value)
```

Refs are also available to mounted components during tests.

If that isn't suitable, I'd definitely opt for using a `data-` approach like you already touched on. It's a common pattern and very widely used for adding extra identification or info to a component.